# How can I take screenshot on failure using Jbehave with Junit on Appium?

Tags: java, junit, automated-tests, appium, jbehave

I am using Jbehave and Junit on Appium. I need to take a screenshot of failure and add them to the report. so what's the way to take a screenshot on Junit with Jbehave on Appium?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

add `screenShot()` into failed assertions, exceptions, or any other statements you want to take screenshot.

```java
import java.io.File;
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;

public void screenShot() {
    String picSavedPath = "screenshot";
    if (!(new File(picSavedPath).isDirectory())) {
        new File(picSavedPath).mkdirs();
    }
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
    String time = sdf.format(new Date());

    //---- Below are essential statements
    WebDriver augmentedDriver = new Augmenter().augment(driver);
    File sourceFile = ((TakesScreenshot) augmentedDriver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
    //----

    try {
        FileUtils.copyFile(sourceFile, new File(picSavedPath + File.separator + time + ".png"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        LogUtil.error(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: HI, @user3669148 , please [Accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) and [Vote up it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) , if this solves your problem. It will help others and myself :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use getScreenshotAs() method .
For example:

public void takescreenshot(String message, WebDriver driver) {
try {

```
        File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
        
        File file = new File("GivethePathto savethescreenshot/screenshot"+message+".png");
        FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile,file );
        test.addScreenCaptureFromPath(file.getAbsolutePath(), message);

    }
    catch(Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```